# progress dialog in android when login is success

Tags: android

This is my Login class i need to display a progress dialog when the user click on login button. how to  set a progress dialog and where to use it

```
          private void login(){

          //Getting values from edit texts
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    //If we are getting success from server
                    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){

                        //Creating a shared preference
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Login.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                        //Adding values to editor
                        editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                        editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);
                       //Saving values to editor
                        editor.apply();

                        //Starting profile activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if (editTextEmail.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    {
                        editTextEmail.setError("Enter your email");
                        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else if(!validateEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString())) {
                        editTextEmail.setError("Invalid EmailId");
                        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
                        //inputLayoutEmail.setError(getString(R.string.close));
                        //return false;
                        //requestFocus(editTextEmail);

                    }

                    else if(editTextPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    {
                        editTextPassword.setError("Invalid password");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //If the server response is not success
                        //Displaying an error message on toast
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Your UserName/Password Wrong\n please verify", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //You can handle error here if you want

                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //Adding parameters to request

            params.put(Config.KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

            //returning parameter
            return params;

        }
    };

    //Adding the string request to the queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    ProgressDialog loading;

    //Calling the login function

    login();

}
```

I need to show a loading option of progress dialog when user clciks on lgin button

Comment: *I need to show a loading option of progress dialog* and where is the problem? there are bazillions examples how to do this ... and you only declare the variable of type `ProgressDialog` in your code ...

Comment: @selvin i am new to android can able to suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login click add progress dialog

```
 ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading");
    dialog.show();
```

and in login method: in response dismiss dialog

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to show progress dialog.

```
ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(BaseActivity.this,
                "Title", "Loading", true, false);
```